# struct example *e: differences between function(&e) and function(e)

Tags: c, function, struct

If I have a `struct example *e`, what are differences between `function(&e)` and `function(e)`?

An example.

This is the first code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct example
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void function (struct example **);

int main ()
{
    struct example *e;

    function (&e);

    return 0;
}

void function (struct example **e)
{
    / * ... */
}
```

And this is the second code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct example
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void function (struct example *);

int main ()
{
    struct example *e;

    function (e);

    return 0;
}

void function (struct example *e)
{
    / * ... */
}
```

What are the difference between those two codes?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **first** you pass the address of a pointer to the struct.  In the **second** you pass the address of the struct.

In both cases `function` can change the structure you pass it:

```
(*e)->x = 10; // First, needs additional dereferencing *.

e->x    = 10; // Second.
```

In the first, you could also give `main()`'s `e` a different value, for example assign the address of another struct to it, or set it to `NULL`:

```
*e = NULL;
```

You're actually forgetting a **third** case:

```
function(struct example e) { ... }
```

here the function gets a copy of the structure you pass it.

Comment: But in the second case can I do `e = malloc ( 2 * sizeof(struct example))` into the function?

Comment: @user You can, but you'll only change `e` locally in the function. The function parameter `e` is passed by value.

Comment: Ok, and in the first one if i do `*e = malloc ( 2 * sizeof(struct example))` I change it also in `main()`, right?

Comment: @user Indeed, with `*e` you basically are accessing `main()`'s `e`.

Comment: _@meaning-matters_. _In both cases function can change the structure you pass it_ But in the second case why I modify the struct?

Comment: @user You ask a generic question to which we give generic answers, so don't ask why, because that depends on your application.

Comment: _@meaning-matters_. Sorry, I have explained badly: in the second case why the function modify the struct? I thought that only in the first code the function could modify the original struct.

Comment: @user Simply because you pass the address of the struct, once the function has the address, it can change the struct.

Answer (score 2):

the first example can change 'e' itself (f.e. Malloc() it and return it).
Both examples can change the content of 'e', if it is malloced.

Comment: _@Peter Miehle_. Do you mean that in the first code I can malloc in the function, like for example `*e = malloc ( 2 * sizeof(struct example));` and in the second case not?

Answer (score 1):

`the structure` is somewhere in a "cloud". You are dealing with pointers to it, which are simple variables holding the adress of `the structure`. In the first example you can change `the pointer` and `the structure`. From the second example you can change only `the structure` but only `a pointer` to it (the local copy).

When you do in the second example an `e = malloc ...`, then `the structure` continues existing in the "cloud", but you create a new one, of which you lose any connection when `function` is finished (= memory-leak). From the aspect of `main` everything remains unchanged.

In C++ you could change your second example like this `void function (struct example *&e)` to have the same behaviour like in the first but with the comfort of an automatic dereferenciation of the "pointer-to-pointer" e (references are some sort of automatically dereferencing pointers).